# Setup Openstack Havana with Docker driver

Tags: docker, openstack, ubuntu-server, devstack

Environment:

```
 Ubuntu 14.04
 virtualbox 4.3.10_ubuntu
 Ubuntu server 13.10 64 bit
 Docker Version 0.7.6
```

I've followed this [1] guide to setup openstack with docker driver.I've used three network adapters in setting up ubuntu server in virtualbox. One nat and two host interfaces. One of the host only interface is to connect to the virtualbox via ssh without confilicting with the host only interface reserved for Openstack. Eventually I was able to run stack.sh successfully [2].

```
 Horizon is now available at `http://10.0.2.15/`
 Keystone is serving at `http://10.0.2.15:5000/v2.0/`
 Examples on using novaclient command line is in exercise.sh
 The default users are: admin and demo
 The password: g
 This is your host ip: 10.0.2.15
 2014-07-18 12:53:51.378 | stack.sh completed in 230 seconds.
```

eth1 and eth2 in virtualbox

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:59:13:60
          inet addr:192.168.92.30  Bcast:192.168.92.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:67:06:99
          inet addr:192.168.57.30  Bcast:192.168.57.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

Here is my localrc

```
  FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.92.0/27
  FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
  FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
  FLAT_INTERFACE=eth1
  ADMIN_PASSWORD=g
  MYSQL_PASSWORD=g
  RABBIT_PASSWORD=g
  SERVICE_PASSWORD=g
  SERVICE_TOKEN=g
  SCHEDULER=nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler.FilterScheduler
  VIRT_DRIVER=docker
  SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
```

But when I try to log into horizon UI(`http://192.168.57.30`) in host ( ubuntu 14.04 ) it says

```
  Forbidden
  You don't have permission to access / on this server.
   Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.57.30 Port 80
```

when with `http://192.168.92.30` it says can't connect. I guess problem is with localrc config. I would appreciate a lot if some one can help me on this.

[1] : http://damithakumarage.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/how-to-setup-openstack-havana-with-docker-driver/

[2] : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KeGmlNcKobWHYyMGZKZFB4cjg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem on Openstack Icehouse. Managed to solve it as below.

Modify **/etc/apache2/sites-available/horizon.conf** with the line "Require all granted" as per below:

```
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Restart apache server. Run the following command on your terminal.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You should be able to access horizon now. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found that openstack havana + docker was sensitive to the version of ubuntu host you were installing into.  IIRC, I could only get it working with 13.04.

I have also found the devstack implementation to be very temperamental after I did manage to get the install working.    For example, network routes would disappear and hosts would become unavailable.

If you are happy to use vagrant, you could try Release 1.1 of my [stratos vagrant box](https://github.com/snowch/stratos-vagrant-box/tree/1.1) which will setup stratos,  openstack and docker for you.  However, I have decided to move away from openstack+docker for the reasons stated above so I haven't used the scripts in a while and it is quite possible that they are broken now.

Comment: No worries and good luck! BTW - have you seen [this post](http://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-will-be-in-openstack-icehouse/)?  This post helped me decide not to spend to much time trying to get openstack and docker working together with stratos.